# failed: port is already allocated

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I use Docker for running Oracle 11g Express on macOS Sierra 10.12.2

https://github.com/wnameless/docker-oracle-xe-11g

This is my error:

```
Last login: Sat Jan  7 22:42:11 on ttys000
➜  ~ docker run -d -p 49160:22 -p 49161:1521 wnameless/oracle-xe-11g
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?.
See 'docker run --help'.
➜  ~ docker run -d -p 49160:22 -p 49161:1521 wnameless/oracle-xe-11g
043d8caecbb45d6e2e5999b69a2f760c20d53ff3aa2fad78cb1eb70acb058a1f
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint serene_lalande (08bb0bd9684c0f92db7b736986bf894d3a57a714324405823496d13e175e7491): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:49161 failed: port is already allocated.
➜  ~
```

I diagnostic:

```
➜  ~ netstat -anp tcp | grep 49161                                  
tcp4       0      0  192.168.1.2.49161      17.188.166.13.5223     ESTABLISHED
➜  ~

➜  ~ docker --version
Docker version 1.12.5, build 7392c3b
```

My Dianostic ID: 20EB9506-CC72-4093-8A15-60E05A841ED1

I don't know why. Before that few weeks, it run success. Nearly, I change, release new DHCP IP. How to run Docker instance has Oracle 11g express success?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another instance of this container already running and consuming this TCP port? Look at `docker ps` and make sure it's not already there, and stop it if it is (before starting another). Only one process can bind to a TCP port at a time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can't launch twice

`docker run -d -p 49160:22`

as this means you want to allocate the port 49160 on the host twice, of course, the second time, you get you error message, try for the second run

`docker run -d -p 49161:22`

Comment: For me, it turned out that MySQL was starting up each time the computer started so it was running in the background without my knowledge. Others who have this problem should also check their System Preferences (on a Mac), click the tab for MySQL and disable _Start MySQL when your computer starts up_.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a different port instead of 49161.  Try a port less than 49152.

You have a pre-existing connection between the the port 49161 on your computer and port 5223 on a remote Apple server.  That port, therefore, cannot be used for anything else until that connection ceases to exist.  Port 5223 is used for Apple's push notifications.  As best as I can tell, your computer so happened to use the random port 49161 to connect to Apple's server this time.  Previously when that Docker container worked, I would bet port 49161 on your computer was not then used.

Whenever you connect to a remote server, your own computer allocates a random port number for that connection.  This time around, your computer allocated 49161 when it connected to Apple's push notifications service.  Next time, it could be a completely different number.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port